# \multirow without extra &s

Tags: tables

It is possible to somehow modify `\multirow` so that it works like this:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
 \multirow{3}{*}{Tall cell}
   & First right cell\\
   Second right cell\\
   Third right cell
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Notice that there are no `&`s in the second and third lines; the cells must be automatically indented. I want it to look like this:
[image]

Why would I wish for such a useless feature? Because I'm converting an XML document into TeX, and this document uses this logic when building its tables. So I kinda have no choice.

Comment: It is probably possible (especially in easy case where the row span is in the first column) but it's almost certainly easier to do this in the transformation from the xml. It's quite a common requirement when changing table models, so there is code to do that in most xml help forums I'd have thought.

Comment: I'm not that much into other other typesetting languages than TeX. Perhaps it's simply because I'm lacking some knowledge of technical terminology, but my best idea was to google "XML table multirow", and it yielded absolutely nothing. Do you have any better ideas, or could you perhaps find me a link? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Will you have other content in the `tabular` as well? Something before (to the left or above) and/or after (to the right or below)?

Comment: Something to the right, above and below, yes.

Comment: 1) Processing tables is hard. I believe that in general case there is no hope for stream-conversion, and that you have to load a table completely and represent it in memory in some convenient form. 2) I also convert xml with tables to pdf. I failed with the usual latex tables and developed an alternative package `cals`. You might find it useful.

Comment: @olpa, I'm currently looking into your package, and it looks interesting, but I'm finding it difficult to quite understand the syntax with spanned rows and columns. Apparently you need a lot of `\nullcell`s everywhere for making it work. If I were to typeset the above example using `cals`, how would that look? Would I also need to write `\nullcell` on the second and third line, because then I'm kinda back to a problem which is similar to the one I started with.

Comment: @Gaussler Yes, you need a lot of `\nullcell`s, one for each virtual cell in a table grid. In your case, 3 of them. And then `\spancontent` after right-bottom `\nullcell`. Probably a bit strange on the first look, but there are technical reasons behind such approach. +++ Returning back to the question: you can't adapt `cals` to your representation.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with XML, but the following approach may nevertheless work for you:

- Don't use the `multirow` package.
- Instead, set up a second, nested tabular for the rows of the right-hand column.

I.e., something like this:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Tall cell & 
   \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}} % "@{}" suppresses whitespace
   First right cell\\
   Second right cell\\
   Third right cell\\
   \end{tabular}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: "Don't use the [`multirow`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multirow) package." Is this a general suggestion or just for this answer? If it's general, why so?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg - For most applications that would appear to call for a `\multirow`, it's usually quite straightforward to find a solution that doesn't employ `\multirow` at all. For the case at hand (converting an XML-formatted table into a LaTeX format), `multirow` seems to pose some obstacles that can be bypassed via a different solution, such as the tabular-inside-a-tabular method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Mico. Unfortunately, the XML code format cannot possibly be converted into this.

Comment: @Gaussler - Sorry the idea didn't work out for you.

Comment: Well, you do get a one-up from me at least. :-)