# Embed ConTeXt into LaTeX

Tags: tables, xetex, context

I have an XML document which I'm currently trying to converted into XeLaTeX code. I'd like to stick to XeLaTeX rather than move to ConTeXt. However, [a problem relatex to the difference in the table syntax](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212805/multirow-without-extra-s?noredirect=1#comment498612_212805) keeps appearing. Then I noticed [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78443/19809), where it turns out that ConTeXt uses a syntax much closer to the XML syntax I'm converting from when rendering tables. So my question is simple, even if I realise that the answer is most likely no: Is it possible to somehow embed (parts of) ConTeXt into LaTeX so that I can use this ConTeXt table syntax instead of the one in LaTeX.

Comment: no, as you already wrote :-) The only possible way is to write the `ConTeXt` code into an external file, run it with `context` crop it and insert it into the text in the next run as a pdf image.

Comment: That was no surprise, yet a bit disappointing. On the side note, do there exist LaTeX packages that use a similar table syntax?

Comment: ConTeXt itself has several possibilities for a tabular syntax which is a bit confusing. It is similiar to LaTeX, no more no less ... but not supported by a LaTeX package

Comment: you can try `cals` package, it may be better suited for automatic conversion from xml: http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-2/tb101parashchenko.pdf